# Add linebreak or newline in Instagram text from objective-c text

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, instagram-api, format-string

I'm using the Instagram API from Xcode but I can not insert a line break in text using `\n`. Can anyone help me adding a new line in the caption/comment on instagram text from XCode?

```
    NSString *repostText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#Repost %@ com #AppRepost.\r\n                      ・・・                            \r\n", userNameStr];
```

Comment: Why the \r? \n should be enough on its own.

Comment: Clarify your problem. What is the issue? What results are you expecting?

Comment: I need add break line in comments Instagram. I put \n to new line but not work. And \r if equals cr but don't work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the problem.

After many attempts, I managed to line break in Instagram comments using the  [Python source code encoding](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm)!

```
NSString *breakLine = @"\u2029";
```

This code

> \u2029" - 'PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR'

Answer (score 0):

```
1.[NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@\r%@",string1,string2];



2.[NSString StringWithFormat:@"string1\rstring2];
```

Try this